# Cloud template deployment/testing cost and how to reduce it

Tags: templates, cloud

I’m new to cloud world specially on testing part.

I have question related to cloud deployment cost.

So in any market place like AWS, GCP etc market place, companies place their template which can be used by client for deployment and further usage.

But to test these template in market place, we need to deploy the template sometime once a day or sometimes multiple times a day, so each time we deploy a template does it involve cost?

I understand if I transfer data from this deployed machines then cost is incurred.

So how can we reduce this cost? Is their any alternate available to reduce or eliminate this cost? Such that we can deploy the template without or with very minimum cost. Anyone who are doing this type of testing can share their experience?

Thanks for your time and appreciate you help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create cloud infrastructure from the template then you are charged for the time that you use per minute or per hour for example.

Network out is charged sometimes between zones of a region or from one region to another.

To reduce cost, try to customize the template deployment and not use the template defaults.

For example:-

```
*   Use SPOT instances instead of ONDEMAND.
*   Use smaller instances ( t3.micro ) instead of some big instance
*   Try to create zonal/regional deployment rather than multi regional
*   Try to use free tier account which has many services 
 free to certain extent, make sure you use allowed resources https://aws.amazon.com/free/
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay for the suggestions!